# second order neighbors of graph nodes in R

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix, igraph

I am looking for an efficient way to find the neighborhoods of exact degree of all nodes in a large graph. Even though it stores graphs as sparse matrices, `igraph::ego` blows up:

```
require(Matrix)
require(igraph)
require(ggplot2)

N <- 10^(1:5)
runtimes <- function(N) {
  g <- erdos.renyi.game(N, 1/N)  
  system.time(ego(g, 2, mindist = 2))[3]
}
runtime <- sapply(N, runtimes)
qplot(log10(N), runtime, geom = "line")
```

[image]

Is there a more efficient way?

Answer (score 1):

Using adjacency matrices directly provides a significant improvement.

```
# sparse adjacency-matrix calculation of indirect neighbors -------------------

diff_sparse_mat <- function(A, B) {
  # Difference between sparse matrices.
  #   Input: sparse matrices A and B
  #   Output: C = (A & !B), using element-wise diffing, treating B as logical
  stopifnot(identical(dim(A), dim(B)))
  A <- as(A, "generalMatrix")
  AT <- as.data.table(summary(as(A, "TsparseMatrix")))
  setkeyv(AT, c("i", "j"))
  B <- drop0(B)
  B <- as(B, "generalMatrix")
  BT <- as.data.table(summary(as(B, "TsparseMatrix")))
  setkeyv(BT, c("i", "j"))
  C <- AT[!BT]
  if (length(C) == 2) {
    return(sparseMatrix(i = C$i, j = C$j, dims = dim(A)))
  } else {
    return(sparseMatrix(i = C$i, j = C$j, x = C$x, dims = dim(A)))
  }
}
 
distance2_peers <- function(adj_mat) {
  # Returns a matrix of indirect neighbors, excluding the diagonal
  #   Input: adjacency matrix A (assumed symmetric)
  #   Output: (A %*% A & !A) with zero diagonal 
  indirect <- forceSymmetric(adj_mat %*% adj_mat) 
  indirect <- diff_sparse_mat(indirect, adj_mat)  # excl. direct neighbors
  indirect <- diff_sparse_mat(indirect, Diagonal(n = dim(indirect)[1]))  # excl. diag.
  return(indirect)  
}
```

for the Erdos Renyi example, in half a minute now a network of 10^7, not 10^5 can be analyzed:

```
N <- 10 ^ (1:7)
runtimes <- function(N) {
  g <- erdos.renyi.game(N, 1 / N, directed = FALSE)
  system.time(distance2_peers(as_adjacency_matrix(g)))[3]
}
runtime <- sapply(N, runtimes)
qplot(log10(N), runtime, geom = "line")
```

[image: the new runtimes]

The resulting matrix containst at (i, j) the number of paths from i to j of length 2 (excluding paths that include i itself).